# Unable to std::bind member function

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I've written the following class:

```
class SomeClass {
private:
    void test_function(int a, size_t & b, const int & c) {
        b = a + reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&c);
    }
public:
    SomeClass() {
        int a = 17;
        size_t b = 0;
        int c = 42;
        auto test = std::bind(&SomeClass::test_function, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3);
        test(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

On its own, this code looks fine in the IDE (Visual Studio 2015) but when I try to compile it, I get the following errors:

```
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'    Basic Server    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits  1441    
Error   C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found    Basic Server    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits  1441
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I also wrote this version:

```
class SomeClass {
private:
    void test_function(int a, size_t & b, const int & c) {
        b = a + reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&c);
    }
public:
    SomeClass() {
        int a = 17;
        size_t b = 0;
        int c = 42;
        auto test = std::bind(&SomeClass::test_function, a, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
        test(b, c);
    }
}
```

I get the exact same errors.

Comment: lambda version: `auto test = [this](int a, size_t& b, const int& c) { this->test_function(a, b, c);}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're forgetting the fourth parameter to the `std::bind` and that is the instance on which you want to call a non-static member function. Since it doesn't operate on the (non-existent) class member data, I reckon it should be `static`, in which case you don't need an instance.

That being said, if you want to bind to a non-static member function, you can do:

```
auto test = std::bind(&SomeClass::test_function, this, std::placeholders::_1,
                      std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3);
// you can also bind *this
```

or (this does not make sense with no bound parameter - bind `a`, `b`, `c` if you like):

```
auto test = std::bind(&SomeClass::test_function,
                      std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2,
                      std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4);
test(this, a, b, c); // you can also pass a reference
```

and stuff like that.

Comment: It is also possible to make the function static and not require a instance at all.

Comment: @callyalater Making it static is not an option in my specific scenario, but good to know.

Answer (score 3):

When using `std::bind` to a member function, the `this` pointer needs to feature (i.e. it needs access to an instance of the class). Either captured as an argument to the `bind` or as an argument later when the bound type is called.

For example;

```
auto test = std::bind(&SomeClass::test_function, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3);
test(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pass in the reference to the object that `SomeClass::test_function` will run on (most likely `this`). [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind#Notes) describes how `std::bind` works.

Another option is to make `SomeClass::test_function` a static member function which requires no instance to be passed into bind.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `bind` to capture a pointer to member function, the first argument to the resulting `bind` object has to be something that refers to an object of a suitable type. Since you're binding to `SomeClass::test_function` you need an object of type `SomeClass` to apply it to, so the first argument to `test` has to be an object of type `SomeClass` or a pointer to an object of type `SomeClass`. For starters, try calling it like this:

```
test(this, b, c);
```